# Sleeping problems

Tags: discipline, sleep-deprivation

Hi everyone I am new in this field and I have so many questions but I believe the most important  for now is how to recover a good sleep pattern for my wife.

Well my daughter is 11 month old chronological and corrected is 9 month. She born premature with just 29 week from then to now has been a really difficults days.

In the last 2 or 3 weeks She wakes up more than 3 times in the night and She try to play with us it doesn't matter that she is almost falling asleep, I called playing in a zoombie mode and she just want to be with her mom and rejects anything from my side.

We are trying with a more strict sleeping rutine (bath, story time, sleep) and at the beginning this work really well but now she is getting this behaviour again.

I Believe this is related to the stimulation that we give to her with different activities, such as swimming, playing in parks among others. But how i can still stimulate her and get a good sleeping  time?

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Oh man you won't like this - we had similar sleep issues when our girls were younger. Nothing ever worked. Just a lot of dealing with it until one day, each in their own time, they just normalized a little. Took about 4 years. I still can't sleep through the night though cause I always think someone is getting up again. You might have to prepare your minds for the possibility that it will be a few more years of bad sleep. Only thing we never really tried was letting them cry to sleep. Seemed too mean. In the end we're fine. Just really tired for a really long time.

Comment: Does she feed during the night?

Comment: Does the mother have to be there for feeding? Could there be a bottle feed? Is it possible for both parents to take turns? Is there a relative who could come and allow her to sleep at another time of day -- so that there could be 3-4 hours of uninterrupted sleep once a day? Could you hire a sitter if there is no relative?

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys. Well about feeding at night, my wife reply that she feeds her in the night just if she demanded.

Comment: We tried to take turns but every time that I go for her at night she hates me. She cries until my wife arrives, it is like noooo the demon is here. BUT during the day she loves me.

Comment: We are alone in Australia all our family is in Chile. I have the opportunity to study overseas and my wife came with me =). Baby sisters and childcare are so expensive here, we cannot afford that right now. Btw, this night was better she fell asleep really quickly and just woke up because the nappy was full.

Comment: I still wondering if there is any method or something that we can try. Can we crate a list of possible actions that help for some of you?

Comment: Your wife might not like this but have you tried sleeping with the baby? Like same bed time and everything. If you are there from laying down and she wakes and knows youre there she might not get so mad. I slept with our girls for over a year. It was not hard transitioning them out of co-sleeping but people will warn you that it is dangerous. It could be if you're a deep sleeper but I was always in panic that I would roll on them so I learned to not move. Queen bed so there was plenty of space. Mattress on floor so no chance of falling off.

Comment: @KaiQing [Link Dr Sears on co-sleeping](http://www.askdrsears.com/topics/health-concerns/sleep-problems/sleep-safety/cosleeping-safely) That is a link to one of his answers, but if you google Dr Sears co-sleeping, he is truly an expert in this area. It **is** something to consider **if** you are comfortable with the idea.

Answer (score 2):

My best suggestion is for your wife to sleep when you get home. As soon as the baby has been fed, she sleeps for as many hours as possible. You need to sleep, too. Perhaps you could make room for the baby and either your wife or you could sleep with her separately  until your child is sleeping better. I understand that the baby is showing a preference right now, but if she is safe, clean and fed, then she will just have to accept you. Perhaps weekends you could try to be more helpful and allow your wife some time away from the baby. I know it does not seem fair when you have to work but I promise you, hers is the harder job right now. She is always 'on'. You may not notice your breaks or lunch times, but even a few minutes of 'you' time is a miracle. You have to support each other.

It takes time for routines to be routine. Just look out for each other and you will get through it. Do try to be kind to each other, it will really help both of you.

Answer (score 0):

We had turns. One was keeping touch with the baby when (s)he woke up at the night. Lets call this parent nightguard. NG would try to tell to the baby: It is night and we are sleeping. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. No talking to the baby beyond that. Stimulation at night keeps baby up.

When it was my time to guard the baby I petted babys back or just held my hand lightly on babys shoulders (our babies usually sleep belly down).

When it was time to feed the baby, nightguard did pick baby up for feeding.

This way I got some sleep every second night, so did my wife.

The real problem is when baby is trying to adjust daily routines and keeps waking up at night. Schedule might be off 1-2 months. When breast feeding ends there will be another set of sleeping trouble.

Comment: In North America (and probably many other places), we are taught "back to sleep", which means babies sleep on their backs. The reasoning is that is reduces the danger from sleep related deaths.  [LINKwith information](https://www.nichd.nih.gov/sts/about/Pages/default.aspx)  Please consider reading the link if you still have an infant.

Comment: That is true. We try to keep the baby sleeping sideways or on its back but babies keep turning around.

Comment: Most SIDS baby deaths happen prior to the child rolling over, though. There is no 'cure', only best methods and practises. There are many helpful suggestions on that site.